# How do I force apps to start in hide mode? (Mac Login Applications)

Tags: xcode, macos, cocoa, applescript

Some apps like Telegram or Slack starts wide open even with set in "Hide mode" on Mac login

There are some script or config to force an app to launch in hide mode ?

With Applescript I already try:

```
tell application "Mail" to launch
tell application "System Events" to set visible of process "Mail" to false
```

But is not what I search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In vanilla AppleScript, the `launch` command is supposed to launch an app in the background, but not hidden. Some apps use panels for their interfaces (rather than normal windows) and panels tend to pop up to the head of the window hierarchy, so `launch` doesn't really help. I could muck around trying to find a pure AppleScript solution to this, but in this case it's straightforward to invoke objective-C (requires Leopard or above).

```
use AppleScript version "2.4"
use framework "AppKit"
use scripting additions

set targetApp to "Telegram"
my openAppSilently:targetApp

on openAppSilently:appToOpen
    set appPath to POSIX path of (path to application appToOpen)
    set sharedWorkspace to current application's class "NSWorkspace"'s sharedWorkspace()
    set appUrl to current application's class "NSURL"'s fileURLWithPath:appPath
    set config to current application's class "NSWorkspaceOpenConfiguration"'s configuration()
    set config's activates to false
    set config's hides to true
    sharedWorkspace's openApplicationAtURL:appUrl configuration:config completionHandler:(missing value)
end openAppSilently:
```

To run this at login, you'll either want to turn it into an AppleScript application that you can put in the Login Items, or write a launchd agent that runs the script at login.  See [this question's answers](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/29119/how-can-i-make-an-applescript-activate-upon-logging-in).

I've tested this on Telegram, but not Slack...

Answer (score 1):

For those not already importing Objective-C frameworks, then you'll want to avoid the overhead of doing so by sticking to vanilla AppleScript, for which one can simply use the **`run`** command for a silent launch:

```
run application "Mail"
run application "Telegram"
```

Comment: And even more oddly, this is a better answer; I'm not sure why mine got selected. Weird...

Comment: @TedWrigley That's kind, but they both have utility and the OP's tags do include [tag:cocoa] and [tag:xcode], so yours would likely slot in usefully. You can probably forgo declaring `appPath` and `appUrl`, as **`path to...`** returns an `alias`, which can be used directly as the `URL` parameter for `openApplicationAtURL:`.